# Add stroke to a drawable with xml

Tags: android, xml, border, drawable

I create a background for a button with XML this is what I got now : 
[image]

And i would like to have a border around the white plus like this :
[image]

Here's my code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/yellowLight"/>
                <stroke
                    android:width="4dp"
                    android:color="@color/yellowDark" />
                <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item
            android:bottom="60dp"
            android:drawable="@drawable/white_plus"
            android:left="60dp"
            android:right="60dp"
            android:top="60dp">

            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="50dp"
                    android:color="@color/yellowDark" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

At the bottom of the code you have the stroke I try to implement but this is not working, thanks for you help.

Comment: better solution to this sort of problems, that you can have the plus icon with stroke so you wouldn't have to that in complex way with xml.

Comment: yes I know but I didn't find it with the stroke and I'm sure it's possible to do this with xml